# Triggered send status queued, need to get an alert

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email-template, ssjs, triggered-send

I have tried try catch block in my email template to get the error handled and then in catch block trying to do a triggered send activity to send email to the admin, but this is not working.

Is there any way to achieve this, if the triggered send is queued the admin should get an alert message with the particular error.

(Adding the code I have been trying but getting an error as maxQueueArray is undefined)

```javascript
<script runat=server>
  Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");

  var mid = 'hardcodedMID';
  var dev = 0;
  var allTriggers = 1;

  var alertEmailAddress = 'me@company.com';// adding the admin email id
  var alertSubKey = 'me@company.com'; //adding the admin email id
  var now = new Date();
  var start = now.getTime();
  var timeOut = 1680000; //28 minutes
  //60000 milliseconds in a minute

  if (allTriggers) {
    var tsdArray = getTSDKeys(mid);
    var length = tsdArray.Results.length;
  } else {
    var tsdArray = ["ExternalkeyofTSD1","ExternalkeyofTSD2","ExternalkeyofTSD3","ExternalkeyofTSD4"]
    var length = tsdArray.length;
    var maxQueueArray = [1,1,1,1,1]; //Enter max queue here. Can make an array as well, if different maxes per TSD
  }

  if (!maxQueueArray || maxQueueArray.length == 0) {
    var maxQueueDefault = 1; //Default for if not using maxQueueArray
  }

  if (dev) {
    timeOut = 10000;
    maxQueueArray = [];
    maxQueueDefault = 1;
  }

  var alertArray = []
  var queueAlertArray = []

  do {

    var failures = 0;

    for (i=0; i < length; i++) {
      if(allTriggers) {
        var customerKey = tsdArray.Results[i].CustomerKey
      } else {
        var customerKey = tsdArray[i]
      }
      var queued = getTSDQueue(customerKey);
      var alreadyFail = Stringify(alertArray).indexOf(customerKey);
      dev ? Write('<hr><br>') : '';
      dev ? Write('CustomerKey: ' + customerKey + '<br>') : '';
      dev ? Write('Queue: ' + queued + '<br>') : '';
      dev ? Write('RunTime: ' + (new Date().getTime() - start) + '<br>') : '';

      var queueArrLength = maxQueueArray.length;

      // changes maxQueue to array value if exist and equal to i
      if (maxQueueArray.length > 0 && maxQueueArray.length <= i) {
        var maxQueue = maxQueueArray[i];
      } else {
        var maxQueue = maxQueueDefault;
      }

      if (queued > maxQueue) {

        if (alreadyFail < 1) {
          dev ? Write('<span style="color:red; font-weight:bold;">Queue Failure</span><br>') : '';
          alertArray.push(customerKey)
          queueAlertArray.push(queued)
          failures += 1
        }
      }
    }

    dev ? Write('<br>FAILURES: ' + failures + '<br><br><br>') : '';

    if (failures > 0) {
      var alertStr = Stringify(alertArray).replace('[','').replace(']','');
      var queueAlertStr = Stringify(queueAlertArray).replace('[','').replace(']','');
      var alertTrigger = sendTSDAlert(alertStr,queueAlertStr,alertEmailAddress,alertSubKey)
      dev ? Write('<br>' + Stringify(alertTrigger) + '<br>') : '';
    }

  } while((new Date().getTime() - start) < timeOut)



  /************************* FUNCTION LIST ************************/

  function getTSDKeys(mid) {
    var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();

    /* Set ClientID */
    if (mid) {
      prox.setClientId({ "": mid }); //Impersonates the BU
    }

    var cols = ["CustomerKey", "TriggeredSendStatus"];
    var res = prox.retrieve("TriggeredSendDefinition", cols, filter);

    var results = res

    return results;
  }

  function getTSDQueue(customerKey) {

    var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();

    /* Set ClientID */
    if (mid) {
      prox.setClientId({ "": mid }); //Impersonates the BU
    }


    var cols = ["CustomerKey","Queued"];
    var filter = {
        Property: "CustomerKey",
        SimpleOperator: "Equals",
        Value: customerKey
    };
    var res = prox.retrieve("TriggeredSendSummary", cols, filter);

    var queue = res.Results[0].Queued

    return queue;
  }

  function sendTSDAlert(alertStr,queueAlertStr,emailAddress,subKey) {

    var proxy = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
    var customerKey = "TSD_AlertTrigger"; // adding the triggered send defination external key
    var name = "TSD_AlertTrigger"; // adding the triggered send defination name

    var ts= {
           TriggeredSendDefinition: {CustomerKey: customerKey, Name: name}
           ,Subscribers: [ {
                  EmailAddress: emailAddress
                , SubscriberKey: subKey
                , Attributes: [
                    {
                     Name: 'tsdList',
                      Value: alertStr
                   },
                   {
                    Name: 'tsdQueue',
                    Value: queueAlertStr
                   }
                ]
            }]

        };

    var res = proxy.createItem("TriggeredSend", ts);

    return res;
  }

  </script>
```

Below is the email template code I am using:

```
    <!-- %%[ 
    set @tsdList = AttributeValue("tsdList")
    set @tsdQueue = AttributeValue("tsdQueue")

    set @tsdListRows = BuildRowsetFromString(@tsdList,",")
    set @tsdQueueRows = BuildRowsetFromString(@tsdQueue,",")

    ]%%-->
    The following Triggers have exceed queue limits:<br>
    <!-- %%[FOR @i=1 TO Rowcount(@tsdListRows) DO
     SET @RowList = Row(@tsdListRows,@i)
     SET @RowList1 = Field(@RowList,"RowList1")

     SET @RowQueue = Row(@tsdQueueRows,@i)
     if @i >= 1 THEN
     ]%%-->
       <hr>
     <!--  %%[ endif ]%%-->
     <br>
     Trigger CustomerKey: <!-- %%=Substring(TRIM(Field(@RowList,1)),2,SUBTRACT(Length(TRIM(Field(@RowList1,1))),2))=%%--><br>
     Trigger Queue Count: <!-- %%=Field(@RowQueue,1)=%%--><br>
    <br>
    <!--%%[ NEXT @i ]%%-->
```

Comment: You tsdArray and maxQueueArray must have same length

Comment: @LukasLunow , Oh yes, I have mentioned that correctly, actually while posting here I missed to mention. The error what I am getting is maxQueueArray is not defined, as I am using this for same BU I have kept the client id's empty, I am very new to ssjs and unable to get the exact issue in this scenario.

Comment: Inside of the functions. You changed it to `prox.setClientId({ "": mid }); //Impersonates the BU` inside two of the functions, need to change it back to `prox.setClientId({ "ID": mid }); //Impersonates the BU`. That should take care of any ClientID issues.

Comment: After that, I was able to run it successfully using your code. Both for 'All TSDs' and for a set array of them.

Comment: @Krisha You are commenting out the outputs. Your inline AMPscript should not have `<!--` and `-->` around them. Remove those and it should display as expected. The blocks are fine as long as you are not outputting content inside them. But if you put comments around the inline functions (`%%= =%%`) it will hide them.

Comment: @Gortonington, I have tried that as well, still no data is coming, the triggered send data extension I am using contains the fields as tsdList and tsdQueue apart from subscriber key and email address. I hope this is correct.

Answer (score 2):

The issue with queued emails in triggered sends is that they at this point don't throw an explicit error which you can query in the system. The error is placed in the log only the moment the send status is set to errored. What I would advise you to do, first of all, is to create monitoring of your triggered sends, to check for the queue length. [Gortonington](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/12730/gortonington) has created SSJS for this particular purpose, which is quite straightforward to implement. You can get the complete code from here: https://gortonington.com/alert-for-your-triggered-send-queue-limits-in-sfmc/

Comment: Thanks @lukas, I am trying this but was unable to get it published in cloudpages, when I added a try catch I am getting this error: Error while setting clientID, the client id is correct which I have used in the code(I got it from the installed packages with all the access)

Comment: @Krisha - Once again, I think this is because SFMC has named multiple things multiple names and some names are duplicated on unrelated things - leading to confusion. The clientID in this case was to reference the MID of the BU, not the clientID in your package for API. You can also leave this empty to utilize the current BU.

Comment: @lukas, thanks for the comment, you mean I just have to mention the MID, I did the same and now there is some issue with the maxqueuearray, error: "maxQueueArray" is not defined, but it defined.

Comment: @Gortonington can you help me with this?

Comment: Can you post what you have (removing PII, etc of course)? likely its a syntax error somewhere that is tripping it up

Comment: @Gortonington, I have added the code to my question could you please help me,getting the below errors:client id not set and maxqueuearray is not defined.

Comment: @Krisha Are you looking to grab just specific TSD or to grab all the TSD in your BU?

Comment: @Gortonington, I have 4 TSD's to which this needs to be done and they are all from same BU.

Comment: turn off `allTriggers` by doing `var allTriggers = 0` and set `var maxQueueArray = [1,1,1,1,1];` to `var maxQueueArray = [1,1,1,1];` so they are the same length.

Comment: @Gortonington,  I tried this, but the cloud page is just loading and loading, not even going to the catch block. Is there anything else I am missing, like in the function getTSDkeys, I am keeping it same as -   var cols = ["CustomerKey", "TriggeredSendStatus"];
      var res = prox.retrieve("TriggeredSendDefinition", cols, filter);

Comment: oh you will need to turn dev on or adjust the timeout part. The script is set to be used in a Script activity to timeout at 28 minutes, which is too long for a page load. The dev value is like 10 seconds I believe. So should handle a single run and not keep running checking the queues

Comment: Great!! its working now, just wanted to ask wether the timeout part is going to check wether the TSD is getting queued during this time period? and as I want the admin to be notified even if th TSD is queued once, so I need to keep the maxQueueArray = [1,1,1,1], right??

Comment: @Gortonington For testing, I kept the the timeout as 300000 ie 10 min, and the if (dev), timeout= 10 seconds(running an automation and scheduled hourly), when this is active at the same time I sent data to the TSD I have added to the array, it got queued 5 times, still no email recieved, I mean the next triggered send didn't work. Is there any adjustment I am doing wrong?

Comment: The timeout is to break the loop. I would read a bit more of the article to get full details.

Comment: @Gortonington, thank you so much for the help :)I am very cose to it,I have created an email template same as you have provided, receving the email as well but values are not getting fetched in Trigger CustomerKey:
Trigger Queue Count: , can you suggest what should be the issue. I am adding the html of email template in my question.

Comment: @Gortonington, I have added the html code, this is the same as you have suggested (added the physical mailing address), for testing purpose I have just added 1 TSD in the array of my SSJS script, in html the values are not getting fetched and it is coming black as: Trigger CustomerKey:    Trigger Queue Count:   , it will be very helpful if you put some light to this.

Comment: @Gortonington, can you please help me with this, I have used the exact same html code you shared in the article for email template without inline comments, and my triggered send data extension contains these fields apart from subscriber key and email: tsdList,tsdQueue. Still not receiving the email when queued, I set the queue limit as 0 as I need the notification even if 1 request is queued.

Comment: @Gortonington, I have successfully implemented this, while monitoring I am getting issues like even after receiving the email successfully i.e the email is not even queued still the admin receiving the email of queue limit reached. Unable to understand why is this happening.